# iOS Safari Debug Console - how can I get the line number of the error?

Tags: jquery, ios, backbone.js, mobile-safari

I have a backboneJS project which loads the dependent files using a jQuery deferred object callback - the website loads fine on desktop, tested Android devices and on iPad with iOS 5.1 - a client brought to my attention that the site doesn't work on her iPad with iOS **4.3.5**. Here is my code:

```
$.when(
    // Load the stuff here...
).done(
    // Call jQuery DOM ready code here...
).fail(
    function () {
        for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
            console.log(arguments[i]);
        }
    }
);
```

This is what is sent to the debug console in Safari (minus the line number of the `console.log` statement):

```
[object Object]
parseerror
SyntaxError: Parse error
```

Well that just doesn't help me at all - any ideas how I can pinpoint that parse error without blindly debugging through 15 backbone views and models? Any known old iOS safari bugs with Backbone or jQuery deferreds that I missed during my troubleshooting research?

Edit: Using the following versions -

```
Backbone.js (unminified) 0.9.1
jQuery (unminified) 1.8.0
```

Comment: check http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10037, try an uncompressed jquery?

Comment: Thanks - I'm using a new jQuery, unminified. Updated this morning from 1.7.2 to 1.8.0 rule that out, but alas the issue remains.

Comment: JSON.stringify on the arguments to let you read what it has to say?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue. Found a line of code where the property name was `class`, like `myObj.class = 'foo';` and apparently `class` is a reserved word in older JS parsers. Changed it to `className` and it worked.

On that note, I would still like to know how to view the line number of the parse error in the iOS Safari debug console. If anybody can provide that answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Nikoshr has the right idea, though more specifically you should stringify the object being passed in the arguments. The debug console will truncate about everything so just replace the page content with the dump for your debugging efforts. It won't show any line number likely but if there is a parse error you'll likely see the object screwed up somehow; truncated response text from an ajax call or something - I only mention that because you are `// Load the stuff here` so I imagine you're using `$.getScript` or something else that will return a deferred object. If so, try this:

```
$.when(
    // Load the stuff here...
).done(
    // Call jQuery DOM ready code here...
).fail(
    function () {
        document.write(JSON.stringify(arguments[0]));
    }
);
```

Comment: That definitely makes that `[object Object]` more verbose so I can see what the object is, but it doesn't look "screwed up" at all and it doesn't help with a line number or anything for that parse error - any idea how to pinpoint the error?